A monad law about bind and function composition
This law about bind and function composition type checks:
bind m (f o g) = f (bind m g)

but it is not clear whether it is true and how can it be proved.
How could I prove this? References are welcome.

I think this law does not hold. It would hold (via bind's naturality law) only if f = fmap h where fmap is for the type constructor of the monad.

The law bind m (f ∘ g) = f (bind m g) does not hold.
The types of functions are: m : M a, f : M b -> M c, g : a -> M b.
The law would hold if f were a function of the form fmap h with some h : b -> c. Then the law would hold due to the naturality law of bind.
 bind m (fmap h ∘ g) = fmap h (bind m g)

A function f of the form f = fmap h may not modify any effects in M; it may only modify the wrapped values. But a general function f : M b -> M c may modify effects. The law would essentially say that the composition of effects in m with the effect in f(g) should be the same as f applied to the composition of effects in m and g. But that is not necessarily true, because f may transform effects arbitrarily.
As a counterexample, take M = Maybe, choose all types to be just Int, and let f transform Maybe's effects in some way:
 f :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
 f _ = Just 123

Choose m = Nothing (and g can be any function). Then bind m (f ∘ g) is also Nothing. However, f (bind m g) is Just 123 because f always returns that value. So, bind m (f ∘ g) is not equal to f (bind m g). The law fails to hold.
